# @JsonRootName not work as I want

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jackson, root

**This is my FacilityDTO**

```
@JsonRootName("Facility")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType(name = "Facility", propOrder = { "id", "name", "totalQuantity" })
public class FacilityDTO implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@XmlElement(required = true)
private String id;
@XmlElement(required = true)
private String name;
@XmlElement(required = true)
private double totalQuantity;

public FacilityDTO() {
}

public FacilityDTO(Facility facility) {
    this.name = facility.getName();
    this.totalQuantity = facility.getTotalQuantity();
    this.id = facility.getId();
}// getters setter
```

**This is my message body writer**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new Jdk7Module());
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
mapper.writeValue(out, object);
int bytesCount = out.size();
byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
entityStream.write(bytes);
entityStream.flush();
```

**The output of JSON format is like this**
[image]

**My Questions are:**

1. Why the results seem not correct? I was put @JsonRootName("Facility") and also enable the wrap root feature.
2. Any part I miss?

Comment: I think (although I could be mistaken) this is because it's being returned as an element of a LinkedList. If you just returned one FacilityDTO it should work as expected.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See [Jackson JSON Deserialization with Root Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704255/jackson-json-deserialization-with-root-element)

According to the above, you need to configure deserialization as follows:
`mapper.configure(DerializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);`