# Why can't I unwrap the root node and deserialize an array of objects?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

Why am I not able to deserialize an array of objects by unwrapping the root node?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonRootName;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class RootNodeTest extends Assert {

    @JsonRootName("customers")
    public static class Customer {
        public String email;
    }

    @Test
    public void testUnwrapping() throws IOException {
        String json = "{\"customers\":[{\"email\":\"hello@world.com\"},{\"email\":\"john.doe@example.com\"}]}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
        List<Customer> customers = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(json, Customer[].class));
        System.out.println(customers);
    }
}
```

I've been digging through the Jackson documentation and this is what I could figure out but upon running it, I get the following error:

```
A org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException has been caught, Root name 'customers' does not match expected ('Customer[]') for type [array type, component type: [simple type, class tests.RootNodeTest$Customer]] at [Source: java.io.StringReader@49921538; line: 1, column: 2]
```

I would like to accomplish this without creating a wrapper class. While this is an example, I don't want to create unnecessary wrapper classes only for unwrapping the root node.

Comment: delete the array brackets from the second param while trying to readValue and put them to the email variable. The mapper will mapp the value of the json String to the object of type Customer and then map those emails into an array.

Comment: @ArthurEirich I couldn't quite follow. Could you provide an example?

Comment: see my answer, I figured it out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an ObjectReader to configure the root name explicitly:

```
@Test
public void testUnwrapping() throws IOException {
    String json = "{\"customers\":[{\"email\":\"hello@world.com\"},{\"email\":\"john.doe@example.com\"}]}";
    ObjectReader objectReader = mapper.reader(new TypeReference<List<Customer>>() {})
                                      .withRootName("customers");
    List<Customer> customers = objectReader.readValue(json);
    assertThat(customers, contains(customer("hello@world.com"), customer("john.doe@example.com")));
}
```

(btw this is with Jackson 2.5, do you have a different version? I have DeserializationFeature rather than DeserializationConfig.Feature)

It seems that by using an object reader in this fashion, you don't need to globally configure the "unwrap root value" feature, nor use the `@JsonRootName` annotation.

Note also that you can directly request a `List<Customer>` rather than going through an array- the type given to `ObjectMapper.reader` works just like the second parameter to `ObjectMapper.readValue`

Comment: That worked out just. I was using the old `codehaus` imports. I've now switched over to the `fasterxml`. The reason I'm using the array notation instead of the typereference as abstract classes show up as uncovered when I'm running Corbertura.

Answer (score -1):

it seems you can't escape a wrapper class.
according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704255/jackson-json-deserialization-with-root-element), the `@JsonRootName` annotation will only allow you to unwrap a json that contains a single instance of your pojo:
so it will work for a String like this: `"{\"customer\":{\"email\":\"hello@world.com\"}}";`

Answer (score -1):

This code worked for me:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class RootNodeTest extends Assert {

public static class CustomerMapping {
    public List<Customer> customer;

    public List<Customer> getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public static class Customer {
        public String email;

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
    }

}

@Test
public void testUnwrapping() throws IOException {
    String json = "{\"customer\":[{\"email\":\"hello@world.com\"},{\"email\":\"john.doe@example.com\"}]}";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    CustomerMapping customerMapping = mapper.readValue(json, CustomerMapping.class);
    List<CustomerMapping.Customer> customers = customerMapping.getCustomer();
    for (CustomerMapping.Customer customer : customers) {
        System.out.println(customer.getEmail());
    }
  }
}
```

First of all you need a java object for the whole json object. In my case this is CustomerMapping. Then you need a java object for your customer key. In my case this is the inner class CustomerMapping.Customer. Because customer is a json array you need a list of CustomerMapping.Customer objects. Also, you do not need to map the json array to a java array and convert it then to a list. Jackson already does it for you. Finally, you just specify the variable email of type String and print it to the console.