# Spring boot jackson - deserializes Json with root name

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I have the below Json

```
{
    "user": {
        "name": "Ram",
        "age": 27
    }
}
```

which I want to de-serialize into an instance of the class

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    // getters & setters
}
```

For this, I have used `@JsonRootName` on class name and something like below

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.featuresToEnable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
        return builder;
    }
}
```

But it did not work as expected. If I send something like below, it worked.

```
{
 "name": "Ram",
 "age": 27
}
```

But I want to get the json de-serialized with root name. Can any one please suggest?

I want to spring boot way of doing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson JSON Deserialization with Root Element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704255/jackson-json-deserialization-with-root-element)

Comment: Can you post how we can config it using spring boot?

Comment: Right, perhaps your problem is not a duplicate then.

Comment: @RamBavireddi https://gist.github.com/varren/4a76ec643f5a4b26e46475a110ebe281 this definitely works for me

Answer (score 2):

`@JsonRootName` is a good start. Use this annotation on `User` class and then enable `UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` deserialization feature by adding:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE=true
```

to your `application.properties`.
Read more about customizing Jackson mapper in [Spring Boot Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper)

Comment: Is it possible to do this on a per-route basis, rather than setting it for the whole application?

Comment: can I customize this in the project, means can i have one class to unwrap the root value and another one without unwrapping

Answer (score -1):

Using **ObjectMapper** you can resolve this issue easily. Here's what you have to do :
 - Annotate User class as given below

```
@JsonRootName("user")
    public class User {
    private String name;
    private int age;

        // getters & setters
    }
```

- Create CustomJsonMapper class

  ```
  public class CustomJsonMapper extends ObjectMapper {

      private DeserializationFeature deserializationFeature;

      public void setDeserializationFeature (DeserializationFeature  deserializationFeature) {
          this.deserializationFeature = deserializationFeature;
          enable(this.deserializationFeature);
      }
  }
  ```
- Equivalent Spring configuration

  ```
  <bean id="objectMapper" class=" com.cognizant.tranzform.notification.constant.CustomJsonMapper">
      <property name="deserializationFeature" ref="deserializationFeature"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="deserializationFeature" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature"
        factory-method="valueOf">
      <constructor-arg>
          <value>UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE</value>
      </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
  ```
- Using following code you can test

  ```
  ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
              "applicationContext.xml");
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = (ObjectMapper) context
              .getBean("objectMapper");
      String json = "{\"user\":{ \"name\": \"Ram\",\"age\": 27}}";
      User user = objectMapper.readValue(json, User.class);
  ```

Comment: Can you post how you can do that using spring boot?