# How to tweak the Spring MVC or @RequestBody behaviour to parse json files with and without root elements

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

Using `Spring Boot 2.6.4`, I am trying to tweak the behavior of the `@RequestBody` to parse json requests with or without Root elements without writing boilerplate code in the same controller class.

```
//should emulate the behaviour of the ObjectMapper when the property is set as 'spring.jackson.deserialization.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE=false'

@PostMapping(value = "/method") public void method1(@RequestBody SomeObject someObject) { 

}
```

```
//should emulate the behaviour of the ObjectMapper when the property is set as 'spring.jackson.deserialization.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE=true'

@PostMapping(value = "/method")
public void method1(@RequestBody SomeObject someObject) {

}
```

This is the boilerplate option.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/method2")
public void method(@RequestBody String jsonString) {
try {
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);

      SomeObject someObject = mapper.readValue(jsonString, SomeObject.class);
        //proceed to business logic
    } catch (JsonProcessingException jsonProcessingException) {
    }
```

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37243185/7681514) answer to a similar question might cover what you're asking for

Comment: I'd like to see the @RequestBody behave differently, that means the jackson mapper  will read the root elements whenever needed. The configuration for the jackson mapper should be per method

Comment: My immediate thought is that this isn't possible without forcing springboot to use your own custom-defined ObjectMapper on a per-method basis (which would be interesting to know if it were possible). I believe spring has its own single `objectMapper` in the spring container that it uses for all JSON parsing, and since the unwrap root value feature is a boolean, it could not be changed on the fly and be expected to work consistently.

Comment: I believe Spring has the "@Qualifier" that distinguishes the beans of the same type. If this feature can be supported on the "@RequestBody" it will be good.  Do we have a developer forum for spring, I could post the same question there