# Json Deserialization - Mapping nested object keys directly to class

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I have a json like -

```
{
"type" : "employee",
"details" : {
  "name" :  "ABC",
  "age" : 12,
  "sex" : "male"
  }
}
```

And a Java Class like -

```
public class Person {
String name;
String sex;
String type;
int age;
 ----getters and setters
}
```

I was wondering is there a ways to directly map the attributes of the `details` object to the person class like `details.name` to `Person.name`.
I know this can be achieved with custom deserializers, but I was hoping to avoid it. May be some annotations that GSON or Jackson provides.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do this without a custom deserializer. This could be done by a @JsonWrapped annotation. But that is something that has been discussed but not implemented yet in jackson, no idea about GSON.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to solve this, but what I would do is create the following class:

```
public class PersonWrapper {

   private String type;

   @JsonProperty("details")
   private Person person;

 }
```

EDIT:

If you don't want to add a wrapper class, you can try adding `@JsonRootName(value = "details")` to your `Person` class.

Comment: This is what I am trying to avoid. I understand this would work. But intent here to work within the given class structure

Comment: I just edited my answer. I have never used that annotation before but after reading the docs it seems like it will do what you want. You might also need some configuration changes.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704255/jackson-json-deserialization-with-root-element

Answer (score -1):

you can use @JsonProperties for mapping

Comment: can you share some example ?