# How can I get "JAX-B-like" XMLRootElement class name wrapper in Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jaxb

When Serializing a pojo with JAXB-JSON it can wrap the root element name around the object data.
For example:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="worker")
public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name; //...
}
```

Can give JSON such as :

> {
>        "worker" : {
>           "id" : 1,
>           "name" : "Ashraf"
>        }    }

What are some ways to achieve this using Jackson JSON serialization?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer. For Jackson 2.2 and above

You need to configure your DTO class as follows:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "worker")
```

You need to configure your jackson object mapper as follows:

```
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

For older versions, see here:
[Jackson JSON Deserialization with Root Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704255/jackson-json-deserialization-with-root-element)